# Close a pull request from another PR with 'Close' keyword

Tags: github, pull-request

## Question

Github supports closing *Issues* from a PR with ["Closes" and other keywords](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/user/github/managing-your-work-on-github/closing-issues-using-keywords). Is it possible to close a *Pull Request* from a Pull Request?

## Background:

I interactively rebased a large PR of mine on `br_1` into a more reviewable, merge-able, and semantically useful group of commits on `br_2`. I opened a second PR from `br_2` which should supersede `br_1`.

The original PR should remain open just in case my reviewer needs to dig into the original development sequence, comments, discussion, etc. Once `br_2` is merged, however, the PR on `br_1` is no longer useful and should also be closed.

Github's UI seems to indicate that `br_2` should close `br_1` on merge (see image 1 below), however:

- I have been unable to find this behavior in the documentation
- I was unable to produce this behavior with the following test:

Here, the UI indicates PR#18 will close PR#17.
[image: UI indicates PR18 will close PR17]

Here, PR#18 has been merged, but PR#17 did not close.
[image: PR18 merged, but PR17 not closed]

Is the UI wrong about PR's closing PR's? Am I just missing something here?

Comment: Note: I have successfully closed a PR from a PR using the "close" keyword. I'm wondering whether the example above failed because it's a noop? Further research required.